# Sum values in a column based on strings from multiple columns in pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 4 columns. 3 of these columns contain string values (people's names) and the 4th one has an int value (salary for a job done).

The string values are not unique either, the same string will show up several times in each column, but never more than once per row.

```
data = {
    'worker1': ['Sam', 'Jack', 'Matt', 'Paul', 'Tim'],
    'worker2': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Sam', 'Alice', 'Amanda'], 
    'worker3': ['Alice', 'Aaron', 'Tony', 'Jack', 'Sam'],
    'earnings': [4564552, 4573547, 3567567, 6357653, 7648576]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['worker1', 'worker2', 'worker3', 'earnings'])

print(df)

worker1    worker2    worker3    earnings
'Sam'      'Alex'     'Alice'    4564552
'Jack'     'Amy'      'Aaron'    4573547
'Matt'     'Sam'      'Tony'     3567567
'Paul'     'Alice'    'Jack'     6357653
'Tim'      'Amanda'   'Sam'      7648576
```

So what I need is to sum all the earnings associated to the specific name, regardless if it shows on column1, 2 or 3. I'm not sure if I should use a groupby function for this, build a dictionary or go another route.

This would be what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
workers    total_earnings
Sam        16080695
Alex       4564552
Alice      10922205
Jack       10931200
Amy        4573547
Aaron      4573547
Matt       3567567
Tony       3567567
Paul       6357653
Tim        7648576
Amanda     7648576
```

I'm quite new to pandas so I'm at a place where I'm not familiar with which functions I can use for something like this. I've mostly tried to use a `groupby` function but that was a disaster.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried so far by adding some relevant code. Have a look at [How to provide a Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you MrLeeh, I've added an example of I'm trying to get done. Regrettably all I've tried has been so far off I don't know where to begin. My knowledge in pandas is very limited as of now.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty here comes from the way the data frame has been constucted. All worker names should have been in one column and their respective earnings in a second column. There is a term "tidy data" that is worth finding out about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data .

The solution below rearranges the data frame and once this has been achieved the total earnings for a given name are easily calculated with a groupby.

```
df_list = []
columns = df.columns.tolist()

for i in range(3):
    df_i = df.loc[:, [columns[i], 'earnings']]
    df_i.columns = ['worker', 'earnings']
    df_list.append(df_i)

df_1 = pd.concat(df_list)

earnings = df_1.groupby(['worker']).sum()

earnings
Out[50]: 
        earnings
worker          
Aaron    4573547
Alex     4564552
Alice   10922205
Amanda   7648576
Amy      4573547
Jack    10931200
Matt     3567567
Paul     6357653
Sam     15780695
Tim      7648576
Tony     3567567
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit lengthy, but does what you want:

```
>>> df1 = pd.concat([df.groupby('worker1').sum(), df.groupby('worker2').sum(), df.groupby('worker3').sum()])
>>> df1.groupby(df1.index).sum()
        earnings
Aaron    4573547
Alex     4564552
Alice   10922205
Amanda   7648576
Amy      4573547
Jack    10931200
Matt     3567567
Paul     6357653
Sam     15780695
Tim      7648576
Tony     3567567
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do what I wanted with the following code. It does work, but I don't know if this is the right approach or the most efficient way to do this. Having some validation from someone with more experience on whether this is a proper way to tackle this problem would be beneficial. Thank you for all the help you've provided in this!

```
df1 = df[['worker1', 'worker2', 'worker3', 'earnings']].copy()
df1.dropna(subset=['earnings'], inplace=True)
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df1 = pd.melt(df1, id_vars = ['earnings'], value_name = 'workers', value_vars = ['worker1', 'worker2', 'worker3'])   

df1.drop('variable', axis=1, inplace=True)    
df1 = df1.groupby('workers')['earnings'].agg(np.sum)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'workers':df1.index, 'Earnings':df1.values})
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like your approach. There are some lines you can do without at least for the data frame defined in your question above. Interestiingly, if you use groupby the way it is coded in my other answer you get a data frame not a series and then you can chain the reset_index method to the same line.

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['earnings'], value_name = 'workers', value_vars = ['worker1', 'worker2', 'worker3'])   
df1 = df1.drop('variable', axis=1).groupby('workers').sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Fantastic, so refreshing to see my approach is acceptable hehe! Your code does make it more efficient, thank you so much. :)

Comment: You are very welcome. Actually, I am really impressed by your use of pd. melt. I tried it for my first answer but I guess at 1:30 am my thinking wasn't very clear, so I abandoned it then.